# Populate Postgres database with numbers 1-1000?

Tags: postgresql, populate

I'm a newbie at pgAdmin3 and I want to populate a database in pgAdmin3 with numbers 1-1000. How can I go about doing this? Currently, I have a database created called MyDatabase (with nothing in it). Every row should correspond to its numerical value (row 1 should contain 1, row 2 should contain 2, etc...)

Answer (score 12):

You don't populate a "database" - you populate a *table*:

This can be done quite easily using `generate_series()`

Assuming you have a table called `my_table` with a column named `id` you can do:

```
insert into my_table (id)
select i
from generate_series(1,1000) i
```

Comment: Where does that get typed into on the program (pgAdmin)?

Comment: @ninchicken in the query window. Click the icon that looks like a magnifying glass with "SQL" in it, then press the green "play" icon to execute your query

Comment: Thanks. I've highlighted my table with one column called "id". However, I type in those commands and I get an error saying the table does not exist.

Comment: If you just want a single-column table with the series of 1-1000, add a "CREATE TABLE my_table AS " in front of the answer listed above. That'll create the table and populate it with the results of the select statement.